# Mysql Group Concat ... not quite getting the result I need

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a query that returns the following rows:

```
parent_id   child_id
    12882       12856
    12882       12857
    12882       12858
    12884       12863
    12884       12864
    12884       12865
    12884       12866
```

When I add GROUP_CONCAT(child_id) it returns only one row with the first parent_id and ALL child_id's concat'ed.....

What I need is for the query to return where GROUP_CONCAT gives me 1 record per parent ID and concats the children id's for that parent only... Thoughts?

```
  parent_id   child_id
  12882     12856, 12857, 12858
  12884     12863, 12864, 12865, 12866
```

Comment: please show your query sql

Comment: naveen goyal's ans is useful for you

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause, and it sounds like that is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with group by clause

```
SELECT parent_id, GROUP_CONCAT(child_id)  from tablename group by parent_id
```